# jQuery Greater than non-selector?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to use `greater than` in jQuery without a selector ?

`$('.myClass').gt(2).css('width','100px');`

My problem is that I am using this in a `for` statement and I can't use the selector `:gt()`.

So how would I do this ?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code?

Comment: More explanation please!  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yep - solved :) the `slice` method is exactly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
myItems.slice(2).css('width', '100px');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method, which behaves as you would expect:

```
$('.myClass').slice(2).css('width','100px'); // get the third elements and all subsequent elements and change their styles
```

This has the added advantage of being able to specify a range, rather than just a start point:

```
$('.myClass').slice(2, 5).css('width', '100px'); // select elements 2 through to 5
```

Comment: No, the first example gets the second element and all subsequent elements. http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: @Cokegod Um, 0-based indexing?

Comment: @Tom `slice` matches the syntax for getting bits of arrays.

Comment: awesome thanks :) exactly what i'm looking for. wish that `.gt()` was simply offered as its more intuitive!

Comment: @Tom: `$.fn.gt = function(x){return this.slice(x)}` :-)